# Why doesn't the sequence work if the condition is correct?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I try to make so that in a range of input at a slide through each 5 values 10 units in the sum were added, everything works, but for some reason after 5 on 6 value is added 10 more, and then everything goes normally.

How it works now: 0(0), 1(0), 2(0), 3(0), 4(0), 5(10), 6(20), 7(20) ... 10 (20), etc.

How should it work: 0(0), 1(0), 2(0), 3(0), 4(0), 5(10), 6(10), 7(10) ... 10 (20), etc.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".in_objem").on('input', function() {
    $(".range-indicator").text($(this).val());
  });
  $(".in_nagrev").on('input', function() {
    $(".nagrev-indicator").text($(this).val());
  });

  $(".in_objem,.in_nagrev").on('input', function() {
    var elem = 0;
    var price = 0;
    $(".in_objem,.in_nagrev").each(function(){
     var b = $(this).val()/5;
     var count = 0;
     if(b >= 1)
     {
      for(var i = 0; i < b; i++)
      {
       elem += 10;
       count += 10;
      }
      console.log(elem);
     }
      $(this).attr("count_sum", count);
    });
    
    var v = 0;
    $('.premium-inpts:checked').each(function(){
      v = v + parseInt($(this).next('.flexy-block').attr("price"));
    });
    $("#price-board").text(v + elem);
    $("#output-price").val(v + elem);
  });

  $(".in_objem,.in_nagrev").trigger('input');

  $(".premium-inpts").on('click', function(){
    var sum = 0;
    var n1 = Number($('.in_objem').attr("count_sum"));
    var n2 = Number($('.in_nagrev').attr("count_sum"));
    sum = n1+n2;
    $('.premium-inpts:checked').each(function(){
      sum = sum + parseInt($(this).next('.flexy-block').attr("price"));
    });
    $("#price-board").text(sum);
    $("#output-price").val(sum);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>
    <span class="nagrev-indicator">1</span><span>units1</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="in_nagrev" name="productivity1" type="range" min="1" max="30" value="1" count_sum="0">
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>
    <span class="range-indicator">1</span><span>units2</span>
  </div>
    <div>
      <input class="in_objem" name="productivity2" type="range" min="1" max="30" value="1" count_sum="0">
    </div>
  </div>
<div>
  <input class="premium-inpts" id="a" type="radio" value="work">
    <label class="flexy-block" for="a" price="300">
      <span>Work</span>
    </label>

  <input class="premium-inpts" id="b" type="radio" value="chill">
    <label class="flexy-block" for="b" price="20">
      <span>Chill</span>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="motors-container">
  <input class="premium-inpts" id="c" type="radio" value="Automatic">
    <label class="flexy-block" for="c" price="90">
       <span>Automatic</span>
    </label>

  <input class="premium-inpts" id="d" type="radio" value="Common">
    <label class="flexy-block" for="d" price="0">
      <span>Common</span>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="price-board">Sum: <span id="price-board"></span></div>
<input id="output-price" name="Sum" type="hidden" value="">
```

Comment: Can elaborate more on your question, it's really confusing

Comment: `var b = $(this).val()/5;` I think you want to use floor or mod since you are going to get decimals which is why you are seeing weird things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your code is working like that is because you give b the value `var b = $(this).val()/5;` and then you go with your for from 0 to b.

Than if your value is 6 than `b = 6/5` which is actually `1.2` not `1`.

So, in your `for`, the `i` is first `0` which is lower that `1.2`, then is `1` which is still lower than `1.2`. If you want a simple resolve to your problem just use `b=Math.floor($(this).val()/5;)` which 'returns the largest integer less than or equal to a given number' [mdn link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor).

But I have to say your code is pretty hard to read, so you might want to consider working on readability and maybe efficiency too.

Comment: Thank you so much!